# Nl2br on data except for <li> tags

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, html-lists, nl2br

I would like to be able to get html-formatted data from mysql, and turn the new lines into `<br>` or `<p>` tags.

I have been able to do this effectively with `white-space: pre-wrap` in the CSS, except for with IE7 and under.

My issue is that if I put a conditional nl2br() on the data if the browser is <=IE7, then it would create line breaks on the `<li>` tags, which already have line breaks, creating extra space between the bullets.

Is there a better way to do this?

My test page is:

http://logblog.net84.net/

And my code is (at this point in time):

```
...
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        </head>
        <style>
        p { white-space:pre-wrap;white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word }
        </style>
        <body>
        <?php 
...
        $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pw) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($db);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo '<h2>'.$row['post_title'].'</h2>'; 
          echo '<p>'.$row['post_content'].'</p>';
          }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get around WordPress's automatic Paragraph replacement? If so there is a built-in a function for you - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

If not this then can you be a little more specific - it looks like your test page link did not come through on the post?

Comment: And does the wpautop() not work the way you want? - e.g. echo '<p>'.wpautop($row['post_content']).'</p>'; - obviously you'd need to take out the CSS

Comment: In fact you shouldn't need to wrap it in P tags either

Comment: It worked!  Thanks.  I was unaware of the wpautop function.  Couldn't find it.  It's my first time with WordPress.  It looks like quite a big function, too.  I probably couldn't have guessed to type all of that. :)

Comment: No worries - glad it worked. I must admit it took me ages finding that function the first time I needed it - it's not a very well sign posted function for some bizarre reason.